# how to not track workflow generated emails in CRM

Tags: email, workflow, tracking, dynamics-crm-online

we are using CRM Online. we have a few automatic workflows that generate emails from user that created an activity that kicks of the WF, to a contact within CRM.  these generated emails automatically become email activities in CRM.

is there a way to prevent that? prevent these CRM generated emails from becoming activities?

thanks,
Inna

Answer (score 0):

Slightly confusing question, to clarify you want to:

1. Send an email from CRM.
2. Don't show the email activity record in CRM.

If you want CRM to send an email it will always create an email activity.

So its just a case of getting rid of the email activity after the email is sent, you could:

1. Create a custom workflow activity/plugin to delete the email activity immediately after it is sent.
2. Setup a bulk delete job to remove the email activities on a regular basis. See [Delete data in bulk](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg334418.aspx).

Comment: sorry about the confusion.  yes it is what we want.   i have a bulk delete job already, but min period to run is 7 days which seems like a lot for us. the users do not want to see these activities.


i thought about a plugin,  is there a way to delete this record after its created via a workflow, without writing custom code?